# Java - String to Double Issue

Tags: java

I am trying to convert String to Double in Java. I get following String from client, "1131.00" but When I convert it to Double, I get back 1131.0, which is NOT correct. I am expecting 1131.00 (.00 - with two zeros)

```
_dPaymentAmt = ConvertUtil.stringToDouble(sPaymentAmt, 0.0);

public static double stringToDouble(String str, double dDefaultValue)
        throws Exception
        {
        double doubleValue = 0;

        try
            {
            doubleValue = Double.parseDouble(str);
            }
        catch (Exception e)
            {
            doubleValue = dDefaultValue;
            }

        return doubleValue;
        }
```

How can I maintain two zero's after decimal?

**EDIT:** One of the intermediary layer removes decimal period to send the value to bank and bank divides it by 100 to calculate decimals. So if I send 1311.0, bank charges 131.10 ...so I have to maintain two decimal points keeping it as a DOUBLE value.

Comment: Uhm, keep it as a `String`?

Comment: And maybe use `DecimalFormat`?

Comment: What do you mean by 'I get back'? Do you convert it back to a `String`?

Comment: Mathematically, what is the difference between the number 1131.0 and 1131.00?

Comment: @Alex - You don't seem to understand the fact `1311.0` and `1311.00` are the exact same `double` values.

Comment: @Alex - paying attention to details is amazing; try it.  The double value is "1311.0".  When you output the double value and send it to some other system, you must format the value as desired.  Try reading the String API, you will find the printf method.  Read that

Comment: "the intermediary layer removes decimal period to send the value to bank and bank divides it by 100 to calculate decimals" suggests to me that the intermediate layer expects an integer number of cents, so that is what it should be given.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`double` does not retain insignificant decimal digits. It's just a magnitude - so 1131 == 1131.0 == 1131.00. It *is* correct to convert "1131.00" to 1131.0. It may not be what you want, but it's correct.

If you're actually trying to store a value which always has two decimal digits (e.g. a currency) you should probably not be using `double` to start with. Either use `BigDecimal` or store an integer number of cents (or whatever type of data you're storing).

Sample showing `BigDecimal` working:

```
import java.math.*;

public class Test {    

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("1311.00");
        System.out.println(bd); // 1311.00
    }
}
```

Note that it's almost *always* inappropriate to store currency values as `double` (or any sort of floating *binary* point number).

If the above doesn't meet your requirements, please give more context.

Comment: @Alex Any **binary** floating point representation is incompatible with preserving the number of **decimal** digits after the **decimal point**. Why do you want to use double at all? Maybe if we knew that we could come up with a solution.

Comment: @Alex: **Why** do you insist on keeping it as a double? How are you sending the value to the bank? (I strongly suspect you're misusing the interface - I doubt a bank would be that broken.) As I've said, either keep it as `BigDecimal` or keep it as an integer (value * 100) and format it manually.

Comment: I understand that and it makes sense that Double has only 1 zero but when I sned to bank interface I send it as Double.toString(double amount) inside an XML ... I guess here I have to make sure to have two zeros after decimal.

Comment: @Alex: So you're sending it as a string. And `BigDecimal` does exactly what you want, as per the code in my answer. So *why* do you want to use `double`?

Answer (score 5):

`double` makes no distinction between `1131.0` and `1131.00`: when stored in a `double` variable, they are exactly the same number.

You might want to keep the numbers as `Strings`, or use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Answer (score 2):

By using `java.math.BigDecimal`:

```
String dblStr = "1131.00";
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(dblStr);
System.out.println("BD is " + bd);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is all formatting. The double object does NOT contain ANY reference to how many zeros there are.... This is all in the way you print it. In math, 1311.00 is exactly the same as 1311, so it does not care about those zeros. You should format it properly if you want to maintain the zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation of keeping two decimal places in `double` datatype doesn't make sense. As far as the numerical value is considered, 1131.0 and 1131.00 is exactly the same thing, hence double datatype will keep the value as 1131.0.

Just keep it as String if you need to save the decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Its as simple as the following piece of code:

```
public void GetTwoDecimal(){

            double d = 2.34568;
            DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");  // this will helps you to always keeps in two decimal places
            System.out.println(f.format(d)); 
    }
```

[Source](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-programming-tutorials/297-java-program-format-double-value-2-decimal-places.html)

Comment: You need to use '0' not '#', from the javadoc: "#  Digit, zero shows as absent "

Answer (score 0):

try like this:  I am sure your problem will be solved.

```
import java.text.*;
public class Demo
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    String str = "131.0000";   // keep as many zeroes 
    double d1 = Double.parseDouble(str);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    System.out.print(df.format(d1));
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a format (for instance format.money("$0.00")). Java probably has a built-in format for dealing with money. Use the money format if you want two decimal places.